# CakePHP Debug Error Undefined property: View::

Tags: debugging, cakephp, view, undefined

I find many of these messages in my debug.log

```
2012-12-03 11:19:19 Notice: Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Sidebar in [/cc/334520/cake/lib/Cake/View/View.php, line 804]
Trace:
View::__get() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 804
include - APP/View/Layouts/**default.ctp, line 72**
View::_evaluate() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 909
View::_render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 873
View::renderLayout() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 527
View::render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 471
Controller::render() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 938
ExceptionRenderer::_outputMessageSafe() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 285
ExceptionRenderer::_outputMessage() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 267
ExceptionRenderer::error400() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 209
ExceptionRenderer::render() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 165
ErrorHandler::handleException() - CORE/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php, line 127
[main] - [internal], line ??
```

in default.ctp, line 72 I have

```
foreach($this->Sidebar->getZone() as $zoneId => $zoneValue){
```

but if I debug($this->Sidebar->getZone()) I get a correct result feedback.
I can't understand why I keep getting this error. Does anyone has an idea for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you calling this sidebar somewhere like `$this->$Sidebar` ? note the `$` here

Comment: No, I checked with project wide search, but I only use it like in my example above.

Comment: it would be cleaner to first grab the content into a variable before you iterate over it.

Comment: @Dave, thanks. I never notived this function and didn't know that this is important.

Comment: @mark, thanks, I will try it this way and will report